# Остановка функции

Tags: javascript, ajax

Нужно сделать Ajax запрос только один раз и если пользователь прокрутит документ на 100px. Сейчас делается постоянно при прокрутке на 1px. То есть если скролл больше 100, функция работает на каждый пиксель скролла, а нужно только на 101 вызвать и остановить. `return false` не работает

```
window.onscroll = function() {
        var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        if (scrolled > 100){
            $.ajax({
                url: '/google', success: function (result) {
                    $('.google-sidebar').html(result);
                    return false
                }
            });
        }
        return false
    }
```

Comment: А с чего вы решили, что `return false` вообще на что-то должен влиять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### В первом приближении

Сохраните в замыкании флаг, который будет вам сообщать был запрос отправлен ранее или нет.

```
(function(){

  var isRequestSended = false

  window.onscroll = function(event) {

    var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

    if (!isRequestSended && scrolled > 100){
      isRequestSended = true

      alert('Make ajax-request.')
      /*
      $.ajax({
        url: '/google', success: function (result) {
            $('.google-sidebar').html(result);
            return false
        }
      });
      */
    }
  }

})()
```

### Во втором

Если вы делаете только один запрос, лучше удалять, нафиг, обработчик, чтобы не грузить систему ненужными проверками.

```
(function(){

  document.addEventListener('scroll', requestAJAXOnScroll)

  function requestAJAXOnScroll() {
    var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

    if (scrolled > 100){

      document.removeEventListener('scroll', requestAJAXOnScroll)

      alert('Make ajax-request.')
      /*
      $.ajax({
        url: '/google', success: function (result) {
            $('.google-sidebar').html(result);
            return false
        }
      });
      */
    }
  }

})()
```